# Eclipse RCP - Custom Perspective, When Activated "Referenced part does not exist yet: "

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I am developing an eclipse RCP application, which uses a custom perspective. This custom perspective lays out some basic elements, like the Package Explorer, Text Editor, and along with that, two of my own custom view parts (similar to each other and would sit side by side on the bottom half of the window.)

When I activate the perspective, this error occurs:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2017-05-08 20:15:29.777
    !MESSAGE Referenced part does not exist yet: {myView2's view id}.
    ContributedPartRenderer$2 {}
```

Here is my perspective class

```
    public class myPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory {
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, (float) 0.5, myView2.VIEW_ID);
    IFolderLayout top = layout.createFolder("top", IPageLayout.TOP, (float) 0.67, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);

    bottom.addView(myView1.VIEW_ID);
    bottom.addView(myView2.VIEW_ID);
    top.addView(IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);

      }
    }
```

And here is my plugin.xml (portion relating to the perspective only).

```
      <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
     <perspective
        class="perspective.myPerspective"
        id="perspective.myPerspective"
        name="My Perspective"/>
       </extension>

    <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension targetID="perspective.myPerspective">
     <view
           id="myView1.VIEW_ID"
           relationship="left"
           relative="bottom"/>
     <view
           id="myView2.VIEW_ID"
           relationship="right"
           relative="bottom"/>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

When I create the IFolderLayout 'bottom', I could put the myView1.VIEW_ID as a parameter, and the error would say it has not been created yet, rather than myView2 not having been created yet. Whichever view class's ID is put in as a parameter, errors out when the perspective is opened, but the other works fine.

How can I fix it so both views behave as normal, and are created and displayed as they should in the custom perspective?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value of `VIEW_ID` in your `myView1` class is not correct. Give the view declaration in the plugin.xml it should be:

```
public static final String VIEW_ID = "myView1.VIEW_ID";
```

Comment: Yes, in my original code, I add the two views to the perspective factory, just a typo in the question which I will update.

Comment: So now, myView1 is in the bottom left corner (as it should be), but myView2's quadrant is split vertically with this empty view part. I think this has something to do with the line creating the folder? Should I try passing null to the creation of the IFolderLayout? Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Please don't ask follow up questions in comments. Accept this answer and ask a new question showing what you are getting and what you actually want.